# extract number from character string in sql and perform calculation

Tags: sql, regex

I want to know what is the easiest way to extract number from character which representing percentage. For example, I have

```
name, rate
Google, 10%
Google, 20%
Uber, 25%
...
```

I want a query that return the average rate group by name

```
Google, 15%
Uber, 25%
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @TrevorClarke  Sorry, I mentioned in the title but forget to repeat in the body that it's SQL.

Comment: input is csv or name, rate are two columns of your table? Also which DB are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of regular expressions, but you don't need it in this case, here's an alternative using native functions, with your sample data:

```
WITH nameandrate AS (
   SELECT 'Google, 10%' AS namerate
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Google, 20%' AS namerate
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Uber, 25%' AS namerate
),

split1 AS (
    SELECT namerate, CHARINDEX(', ', namerate) AS position
    FROM nameandrate
),

split2 AS (
    SELECT LEFT(namerate, position - 1) AS name,
           CAST(
             SUBSTRING(namerate, position + 2, LEN(namerate)-position-2)
             AS int
           ) AS rate
    FROM split1
)

SELECT   name, CAST(AVG(rate) AS varchar(100)) + '%'
FROM     split2
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It really helps. I also have percentage rate in double, so I will just use something like: CAST(SUBSTRING(rate, 0, LEN(rate) - 1) as DECIMAL(5, 2)) numRate

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regex for Extracting;

```
([a-z]+\,[\s]*[\d]+\%)
```

use `InCaseSensitive` Comparison.

You can refer these links for how to use Regex in Sql:

[Regular Expressions in MS SQL Server 2005/2008](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42764/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-SQL-Server)

[Create and Run a CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: I am new to SQL, so could you go over how to generate the query. I guess I need to use GROUP BY and avg, but not sure how to put everything together.

Comment: Do you want to execute this on `sql server` or `mysql`?

Comment: i'm not sure about the difference. I guess SQL?

Comment: There is difference.Because if it is `MySql` you can use `REGEXP` for regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and sorry for any confusion. I think I'm using SQL now on SQL Workbench/J.

Answer (score 0):

The below regexp should do the number striping part. In JS this is how it works.

```
var text = "name, rate\nGoogle, 10%\nGoogle, 20%\nUber, 25%",
     rex = /\d+(?=%)/g,
     res = text.match(rex); //<- ["10", "20", "25"]
```

Comment: is this sql? OP mentioned sql in comments.